# Jquery autocomplete data shows label and store id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have jQuery UI autocomplete input with AJAX source where I want to show the label and not the id; but when user select the label id store in value. I don't want to use hidden field for this. I want store id on same text box. My code is below:
index.blade.php

```
<input id="party_name" class="party_name ui-autocomplete-input" name="party_name" placeholder="Party name" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

JS code

```
$(".party_name").autocomplete({
        source: "/filter/partyname",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".party_name").val(ui.item.value);   
            $("#party_name").val(ui.item.label);             
        }
    });
```

php code

```
$find_cust = $post_data['term'];
        $get_list = PartyName::select('id', 'party_name')
            ->where('party_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $find_party . '%')
            ->get();
        $data = array();
        foreach ($get_list as $table_data) {
            $data[] = ['value' => $table_data->id, 'label' => $table_data->cust_name];
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: **I don't want to use hidden field for this**. Why is it so ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz because i am using dynamic add, edit & delete text box and if i am use hidden field for this then i have to maintain lots

Answer (score 0):

Change you focus function as below

```
 focus: function (event, ui) {
        $(".cust_id").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
```